# How to upgrade python version 3.6.9 to any latest stable python version in azure unbuntu 18.04LTS instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, ubuntu-18.04

How to upgrade python version 3.6.9 in unbuntu 18.04LTS to any latest stable python version

Comment: Please check this once https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-9-0-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Comment: Just FYI, you should probably be aware that changing the system Python version to a version not provided by the regular system updates may mean you're on your own support wise if something breaks. That said, it will probably mostly work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to upgrade to get the specific python version in `Ubuntu 18.04LTS` .

> to upgrade python version 3.6.9 in unbuntu 18.04LTS to any latest
> stable python version

Based on this [***BLOG***](https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-9-0-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) Post by @*MOHIT MALVIYA*,

> Add the following to your cmdlts And just before  mention the python
> version according to your environment requirement (e.g);
>
> ```
>   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 9
> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
> ```
>
> Then to configure python 3 run the following;
>
> ```
> sudo update-alternatives --config python3
> ```
>
> Then check the python version that you have installed then you will
> get the required version(Python 3.6.9);
>
> ```
> python3 -V
> ```

*For more information please refer this Quora*| [***How to upgrade python version in Ubuntu***](https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-9-0-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)